# Namespace routing with ember.js, different approaches with unexpected results

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a simple question, and I need some explanations :

Why doing this works:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter.reopen({
    namespace: 'conversations/' + getSubuserEmail(),
});

App.Router.map(function(){
    // Routing list to raw namespace path
    this.resource('conversations', { path : '/' });
});
```

And doing this doesn't :

```
App.ApplicationAdapter.reopen({
    namespace: 'conversations/',
});

App.Router.map(function(){
    // Routing list to raw namespace path
    this.resource('conversations', { path : '/' + getSubuserEmail() });
});
```

The latter doesn't trigger my model hook when for example, my URL is :

app.rails.local:3000/conversations/someEmail

Thanks.

EDIT :

So with the comment below I rewrote my router with the following code :

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    // Routing list to raw namespace path
    if(getSubuserEmail()){
        this.route('conversations', {path : '/:email'});
    } else {
        this.route('conversations', { path : '/' });
    }   
});
```

Precisions :

When a email is found in the URL, I want ember-data to fill the store with the conversations belonging to a certain subuser whose email matches the one in the URL.

When there is no email found, I want it to retrieve all conversations of all subusers. I have both routes routes in my back-end.

The problem now is that my model hook is NEVER triggered when there is a email in the URL, as if ember-data doesn't recognize my dynamic segment. Any ideas?

Comment: I didn't get what this code should do, but I can tell that you shouldn't use any function call in routes definition. If you want to use a parameter, define your route as `this.route('conversations', { path: '/:email' });`. In yout model hook you can get it via `parameters.email`, where parameters is a first argument of model hook. Ember has a nice docs about routing http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/routing/defining-your-routes/

Comment: Hey, thank you for your time. Please read my edit! I found PART of the solution! I was using location: 'none' instead of location: 'history' in my router! Ill keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have any logic inside App.Router.map. This construction is to describe how your url's should look. Config that you need will look like

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.route('conversations', {path : '/'}, function(){
        this.route('index', {path : '/'});
        this.route('subuser', {path: '/:email'});
    });  
});
```

Then you should create actual routes (if you use ember-cli, in app/routes/conversations/index.js and app/routes/conversations/subuser.js), templates, and write your code. To debug your app you should install an extension, ember inspector (available for chrome and FF). It will show all your routes, controllers and other useful info.